# How do you determine if the DNS server is authoritative

Tags: domain-name-system

How do you determine if the DNS server is authoritative? For example,for 2008 DNS SERVER,if there is no cache,and the transponder is not configured,how can I determine which IP address to use when I go to the root to ask for the IP query resolution? After all,there are 13,right? Since I have done the packet capture analysis before,every time I go to QUERY DNS,the target root IP is different,so do I think there are rules when I choose the root IP?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know how to determine the authoritive DNS server? Do you want to know how the root nameservers work in regard to recursive queries?

Comment: I'm unsure where you're going with your question, but on unix at least, you can run `dig A bla.example.com` to see the `AUTHORITY` flag (and if the TTL doesn't change, the server is also likely authoritative).

Comment: Yes,I want to know how to select one of the 13 IP addresses when the local server iterates the query to the root server because there are 13 IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS server selects one of the 13 root name servers using [round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS). It gets the IP addresses of these 13 root servers from the hints file included in a DNS server installation.

Comment: Please mark it then as the correct answer.